# find next td based on td with span tag in

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to find next td of a td with a span in it?

```
html_text = """
<tr class="someClass">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>A normal string</td>
    <td class="someClass">10</td>
    <td class="someClass">11</td>
    <td class="someClass">12</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="someClass">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Non normal string <span style="font-size:10px">(with span)</span></td>
    <td class="someClass">2 000</td>
    <td class="someClass">2 100</td>
    <td class="someClass">2 150</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
"""
```

To get the td after the td with "A normal string" in it I would simply just find it by:

```
a_normal_string = str(soup.find("td", text="A normal string").find_next('td'))
a_normal_string = re.findall(r'\d+', a_normal_string)
print a_normal_string #['10']
```

However, in the second tr where i need to find the td after the td with a `Non normal string` above method will not work. So how to deal with a td containing spans?

First thought was to find it by regex and compile `a_nonnormal_string = str(soup.find("td", text=re.compile(r'A non normal string')).find_next('td'))` but this is not applicable as well.

This is just an example of two trs but the actually website has hundreds of trs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to solve it with a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function), using `get_text()` to check the text against a desired string (note that `get_text()` returns the complete text of an element including its child elements, but [`.string` does not](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) - it would be `None` if there are child elements - this is actually the reason why your second approach does not work):

```
tds = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "td" and "normal string" in tag.get_text())
for td in tds:
    a_normal_string = td.find_next('td').get_text()
    print(a_normal_string)
```

Prints:

```
10
2 000
```